# How do I pass an accept license argument to the Apple iTMS Transporter installer?

Tags: sh, itmstransporter

I am trying to download and execute the iTMS Apple Transporter installer shell script on Linux. I am prompted to accept the license, but I want to pass the `--accept` parameter to the script so that I will not need to manually accept.

I ran

```console
wget -O iTMSTransporter_installer_linux_3.2.sh "https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/resources/download/public/Transporter__Linux/bin"
```

and then

```console
./iTMSTransporter_installer_linux_3.2.sh --accept
```

Despite passing the `--accept` argument, I still get prompted to accept the license.

The source code from `./iTMSTransporter_installer_linux_3.2.sh` reads:

```sh
initargs="$@"

while true
do
    case "$1" in
    -h | --help)
    MS_Help
    exit 0
    ;;
    -q | --quiet)
    quiet=y
    noprogress=y
    shift
    ;;
    --accept)
    accept=y
    shift
    ;;
    --info)
```

and then in the PrintLicense() method:

```sh
MS_PrintLicense()
{
  PAGER=${PAGER:=more}
  if test x"$licensetxt" != x; then
    PAGER_PATH=`exec <&- 2>&-; which $PAGER || command -v $PAGER || type $PAGER`
    if test -x "$PAGER_PATH"; then
      echo "$licensetxt" | $PAGER
    else
      echo "$licensetxt"
    fi
    if test x"$accept" != xy; then
      while true
      do
        MS_Printf "Please type y to accept, n otherwise: "
        read yn
        if test x"$yn" = xn; then
          keep=n
          eval $finish; exit 1
          break;
        elif test x"$yn" = xy; then
          break;
        fi
      done
```

Comment: Add `set -vx` at the top of the `MS_PrintLicense()` (inside the curly braces). Then you should see each block statement with variables names, each line that is executed with variable names and finally each line (and sub-cmd like `$( echo sample cmd-substition)`) preceded with `+` char and all variable **values** now substituted in place. You should be able to see where `$accept` is breaking down. Good luck.

Comment: The code lacks several crucial details. How does the `while` loop end? How are you calling `MS-PrintLicense`? What's in `licensetxt`? Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

iTMSTransporter installer is packed by **makeself** https://makeself.io/.

The **--accept** parameter is to agree with the license if it is part of **makeself**. However, Apple does not use this capability. So it only unzips the files that are inside the self-extracting script and runs another script inside.

Unfortunately, the internal script does not allow skipping the license. There are more problems with the internal script that can theoretically be solved (skip pagination, force yes from standard input, etc.).

For our purposes, we preferred to use the **makeself** parameters for archive extraction without execution. We then manually copied the itms folder. We use this method in the docker.

```
curl -sSL "https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/resources/download/public/Transporter__Linux/bin" -o ~/installer_package.sh
chmod u+x ~/installer_package.sh
~/installer_package.sh --noexec --target ~/trasporter_install
rm ~/installer_package.sh
cp -r ~/trasporter_install/itms ~/itms
rm -rf ~/trasporter_install
chmod 555 ~/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter
```